# How to import DB connection in another page

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm new to php and i want to import the db-connection details from Db.php to the other page but it's not working.

If code require setup database connection each page

`$bd=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","dbgadget");`

Please help me or give an example how i could access the db-connnection details in other pages.

### Db.php

```
<?php
$mysql_hostname = "localhost";
$mysql_user = "root";
$mysql_password = "";
$mysql_database = "dbgadget";


$bd = mysqli_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user,   
$mysql_password,$mysql_database) ;


if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to database: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

mysqli_close($bd);
?>
```

### Productdetail.php

```
<?php
include('db.php');

$prodID = $_GET['prodid'];

if(!empty($prodID)){
    /// if i uncoment this line then code work fine 
    $bd=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","dbgadget");

    $sqlSelectSpecProd = mysqli_query($bd,"select * from products where id = 
     '$prodID'");
    $getProdInfo = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlSelectSpecProd);
    $prodname= $getProdInfo["Product"];
    $prodcat = $getProdInfo["Category"];
    $prodprice = $getProdInfo["Price"];
    $proddesc = $getProdInfo["Description"];
    $prodimage = $getProdInfo["imgUrl"];
}
?>
```

Comment: Looks like you are already using `include` which is the recommended practice. So what is your question here exactly ?

Comment: Also, you don't need this: `$bd=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","dbgadget");` since you are already creating a database connection in `db.php`.

Comment: if i remove this then its show database connection error

Comment: That is because `$sqlSelectSpecProd = mysqli_query($bd,"select * from products where id =  '$prodID'");` should be `$sqlSelectSpecProd = mysqli_query($db,"select * from products where id = '$prodID'");` (`$bd` should be `$db`)

Comment: $bd  is database connection string see   db.php  file

Comment: Yes you are right. Try removing this line: `mysqli_close($bd);` from `db.php` and see what happens.

Comment: its work now   . so    its not necesory to close db ???

Comment: Not until you know you are finally done with the connection and don't need it anymore.

Comment: but im using sample project   just chage sql to sqli and ru projecct is already complete so what i do? delete mysqli_close($bd); from project??

Comment: You can keep it but make sure you are doing so AFTER you are done with the connection and won't need it anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you seem to be closing your database connection in the db.php file. try removing this line and then re-adding it at the very end of your code in productdetail.php